# Searching the product of 2 numbers in a 2D array

Tags: c

The objective of my code is to find the product of a and b in a 2D Array Multiplication table and add a "^" below it. Not sure how to go about, this is what I've done so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0,j = 0,a,b;
    int array[15][15];

    printf("Enter a value: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter another value: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 15; j++){
            array[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
            printf("[%d]\t", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to find the location where `array[i][j] == a * b`. You can do that right after the assignment to `array[i][j]`.

Then you need to save that position.

And after you print the newline, you need to print another line **if** the value was found, placing the "marker" at the correct position.

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, how do you save the location?

Comment: @Cupboi Simplest is probably to save the value of `j` in another variable. Then you know how many tabs you need to print to get the correct position. Reset to e.g. `-1` before the inner loop, so you can check after the loop if it was set or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce a "flag" variable to tell whether you found a match. Further you need a variable to save the line index of match.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Use a define so it's easy to change size of the array
#define DIM 15

int main(){
    int i = 0,j = 0,a,b;
    int array[DIM][DIM];

    int match = 0;      // Match flag
    int match_pos = 0;  // Position of match

    printf("Enter a value: ");
    if (scanf("%d",&a) != 1) exit(1);   // always check the value returned by scanf
    printf("Enter another value: ");
    if (scanf("%d",&b) != 1) exit(1);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++){
            array[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
            printf("[%d]\t", array[i][j]);

            // Do we have a match?
            if (a*b == array[i][j])
            {
              // yes, set flag and save position
              match = 1;
              match_pos = j;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");

        // Did we have a match?
        if (match)
        {
          // yes
          match = 0;                                   // clear flag
          for (j=0; j < match_pos; ++j) printf("\t");  // print match_pos tab
          printf(" ^\n");                              // print the ^
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple answers? Like 2*2 = 4, what if I only want to isolate the 2nd row, 2nd column 4?

Comment: @Cupboi If there are multiple rows with a match (and there often will be) a `^` will be printed after each matching row. I'm not sure what you mean by " isolate the 2nd row, 2nd column 4"